How to inject config into Custom CacheInterceptor in Next.js
I have created a custom CacheInterceptor to change the cache key:
@Injectable()
export class HttpCacheInterceptor extends CacheInterceptor {
  trackBy(context: ExecutionContext): string | undefined {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest<FastifyRequest>()

    return `${request.hostname}:${request.url}`
  }
}

and use it as so in AppModule
providers: [
    AppService,
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: HttpCacheInterceptor
    }
  ]

I'd like to be able to disable the cache entirely based on value from ConfigService though, but at a loss how to inject the ConfigService in this scenario?

Option 1:
You can inject your ConfigService in CacheInterceptor like this:
@Injectable()
export class HttpCacheInterceptor extends CacheInterceptor {
  private readonly myCacheRule: boolean;
  constructor(
    private readonly configService: ConfigService
  ){
    this.myCacheRule = this.configService.myCacheRule
  }

  trackBy(context: ExecutionContext): string | undefined {

    // do some validation with myCacheRule
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest<FastifyRequest>()

    return `${request.hostname}:${request.url}`
  }
}

It's implicit that you need to import ConfigModule in the AppModule and that there is a variable in your config service with the name myCacheRule.
Option 2:
You can import the real HttpInterceptorService or a mock version of it (that does nothing) dynamically depending on the variable in your config service like this:
providers: [
    AppService,
    ConfigModule,
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useFactory: (
        configService: ConfigService, 
        httpCacheInterceptor, 
        mockInterceptor
      )=>{
        if(configService.myCacheRule){
          return httpCacheInterceptor
        }
        return mockInterceptor
      },
      inject: [ConfigService, HttpCacheInterceptor, MockInterceptor]
    }
  ]

I think this covers your question but I found another question that might be helpful on how to provide a service dynamically depending on your environment variables, it might be helpful:
Inject correct service based on parameter
